# Why doesn't IEnumerable<T> have FindAll or RemoveAll methods?

Tags: c#, linq, collections, extension-methods, ienumerable

It seems to me that a lot of the extension methods on `IList<T>` are just as applicable to `IEnumerable<T>` - such as `FindAll` and `RemoveAll`.

Can anyone explain the reasoning why they are not there?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`RemoveAll` makes no sense since there is no `Remove` etc on that API - however there ***is*** a `FindAll` from 3.5 onwards - but it is known as `Where`:

```
IEnumerable<Foo> source = ...
var filtered = source.Where(x => x.IsActive && x.Id = 25);
```

which is equivalent to:

```
IEnumerable<Foo> source = ...
var filtered = from x in source
               where x.IsActive && x.Id == 25
               select x;
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I see more of the picture now but could I follow up with 2 related questions: (1) why does List<T> implement FindAll as well as Where, assuming they are the same: (2) Why does ICollection not implement RemoveAll since it does implement Remove? Thanks Andy

Comment: @Andy I don't think there is a reason for it, but you can write a extension method on your own, look at my answer.

Comment: @Andy `List<T>` gets a `Where` because it implements `IEnumerable<T>`. Re `ICollection`: because it is not a good idea to add extra methods to interfaces, HOWEVER, it would be perfectly possible to implement that using an extension method on the interface,

Comment: Thanks for those replies. I think the other thing that confused me is that IEnumerable<T> does have a remove method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357554.aspx but on closer inspection it does something different

Comment: @MarcGravell: With regard to `ICollection`, it may not be practical to add methods to an existing interface, but a `RemoveAll` would have been more justifiable as part of a standard collection interface than `Find` or `Remove` [any collection which returns `false` for `IsReadOnly` should be able to implement it, and there's really no way to achieve equivalent functionality without it].

Answer (score 11):

Enumerable does not imply there is an underlying collection, so you can't know whether there is something to remove from or not. If there *is* an underlying collection, you don't know whether it supports a remove operation.

Here is an example method that enumerates odd numbers. If you could "remove" 7 from enumerable, what would happen? Where would it be removed from?

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetOddPositiveNumbers()
{
   int i = 0;
   while (true)
   {          
      yield return 2*(i++)+1;
   }
}
```

What you might be looking for is `Where` and `Except` that allows you to *filter* the enumerable.

Comment: 'Remove' in the context of an enumerable would simply mean you don't enumerate over it.

Answer (score 1):

For `RemoveAll` isn't applicable on `IEnumerable` because IEnumerable is read-only.
For `FindAll`, see Marc's answer.

Answer (score 1):

All `IEnumerable` does is specify that there is a collection that can be enumerated or iterated over.  It does not even specify that the collection can be iterated over multiple times, let alone manipulated.  Therefore, any methods that manipulate the collection do not make sense.  Methods such as `FindAll` would make sense, however.

Answer (score 1):

To be fair something like `IEnumerable<T>.RemoveAll` can actually make sense if what you actually want is a zero length version of a particular collection. Calling it `RemoveAll` does NOT make sense since no `IEnumerable<T>` method implementation should modify a collection.

So in my case I sometimes use a custom extension method I call `Nil`.

```
static IEnumerable<T> Nil<T>(this IEnumerable<T> self) {
  yield break;
}
```

As for `FindAll` as Marc already pointed out is simply called `Where`.